# SetSecurityInfo: Undeclared Identifier

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to set security permissions on an object. This is the code:

```
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {0};
    STARTUPINFO si = {0};
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);

    CreateProcess("C:\\AP\\DataBase\\dbntsrv.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, "C:\\ADP\\SQLBase", &si, &pi);      


    result = SetSecurityInfo(pi.hProcess, SE_WINDOW_OBJECT, PROCESS_TERMINATE, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

But it gives me compile time error of `'SetSecurityInfo' : undeclared identifier`.. and `'SE_WINDOW_OBJECT' : undeclared identifier`.. Any idea why this happens? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [Windows documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379588%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it says you need to include `Aclapi.h`. Have you?

Answer (score 1):

Before starting the process, you should set security attributes, not after it. Or, start process suspended, and then later resume it.

`SE_WINDOW_OBJECT` is not correct for process security. Use `SE_KERNEL_OBJECT`.